# sort DataGridView dont work for me

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have database that i fill on DataGridView.

i try to sort my DataGridView by pressing on Heder like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender,DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
     SortOrder ss = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection;
     string strColumnName = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
     label8.Text = "Column: " + strColumnName + " - " + "sort order: " + ss.ToString();

     if (strColumnName == "Column9")
     {
        if (ss == SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            A_table = "Tmp_Kabat_SfiraTbl";
            SQL = "SELECT Color,Line,Makat,Des,sQty,sNewQty,CountBy_Name,UserName,TermNum,NewQty,Qty from " + A_table + " order by NewQty asc";
        }
        else if (ss == SortOrder.Descending)
        {
            A_table = "Tmp_Kabat_SfiraTbl";
            SQL = "SELECT Color,Line,Makat,Des,sQty,sNewQty,CountBy_Name,UserName,TermNum,NewQty,Qty from " + A_table + " order by NewQty desc";
        }
            dsView = new DataSet();
            adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Main.Conn);
            adp.Fill(dsView, A_table);
            adp.Dispose();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dsView.Tables[A_table].DefaultView;
            this.dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
      }
}
```

its works only one time, it dont change from asc  to  desc  sorting

what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change SortGlyphDirection for HeaderCell, the best way is to do it is in last line of code inside `dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick`.

Here is some nice sorting sample [DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection Property][1]

And now how this will be used in your sample:

```
    private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SortOrder ss = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection;
        string strColumnName = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;

        PopulateDataGridView(ss, strColumnName);

        //change sorting...
        switch (ss)
        {
            case SortOrder.Ascending:
                ss = SortOrder.Descending;
                break;
            case SortOrder.Descending:
                ss = SortOrder.Ascending;
                break;
        }
        dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = ss;
        //change column sort mode...
        dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
    }

    void PopulateDataGridView(SortOrder ss, string strColumnName)
    {
        label8.Text = "Column: " + strColumnName + " - " + "sort order: " + ss.ToString();
        if (ss == SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            A_table = "Tmp_Kabat_SfiraTbl";
            SQL = "SELECT Color,Line,Makat,Des,sQty,sNewQty,CountBy_Name,UserName,TermNum,NewQty,Qty from " + A_table + " order by " + strColumnName + " asc";
        }
        else if (ss == SortOrder.Descending)
        {
            A_table = "Tmp_Kabat_SfiraTbl";
            SQL = "SELECT Color,Line,Makat,Des,sQty,sNewQty,CountBy_Name,UserName,TermNum,NewQty,Qty from " + A_table + " order by " + strColumnName + " desc";
        }
        dsView = new DataSet();
        adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Conn);
        adp.Fill(dsView, A_table);
        adp.Dispose();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsView.Tables[A_table].DefaultView;
        this.dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }
```

For default population you can use something like this:

```
PopulateDataGridView(SortOrder.Ascending, "Color");
```

Comment: thank for the help, but i need to catch the column and the sort type - and make my query from this. can you help me with my sample code ?

Comment: Yes no problem, I have made working sample based on your code. Please look at my edited post. Just for info "Conn" object is used as string and sorry for late response, I had a busy day.

Answer (score 0):

i think if you set:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null
```

and then assign:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dsView.Tables[A_table].DefaultView;
```

it should work (i had similar issue some time ago..), any way you can use DataView order property (without executing sql statement)